# Creating WMS, which can be previewed via ArcGIS JavaScript Viewer, based on buffer model tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wms

I am really new to arcgis, so i think you will find this to be an easy question.

Arcgis docs are abundant, but however, after too much browsing, i cannot find a concrete answer.

these are the elements:

- "depts": a feature class stored in oracle (polygon type).
- using modelbuilder, i've created a simple model: it only plugs "depts" into a buffer, producing an output feature class called "depts_buff"
- now, i publish the corresponding service. under "capabilities" it only allows me to publish as wps.

What i want to do is to create a wms service, which can be previewed via arcgis javascript viewer, based on the buffer operation i just made.

As far as i understand, what i should do is to create a map (a .mxd file) and take the "depts_buff" feature class as a layer and share that map as a service.

Is that assumption correct or is there a way to make maps directly from published services?

Comment: Just for clarification, are you wanting to make a service out of the model, or just out of the depts_buff layer?

Comment: yup, a service out of the model. And the output of that service is what i would like to be able to directly preview with the javascript api. thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're on the right track.  Services are published by adding relevant datasets to an .MXD and clicking File > Share as a service.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/publish-map-services/publishing-a-map-service.htm

Conversely, its also possible to add data published as services back into ArcMap via the Catalog window after creating a connection to the server of interest.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/using-arccatalog/connecting-to-gis-servers.htm

Comment: although not what i was looking for, your answer put me on the trail of something very interesting, thank you.